# What is the best way to represent ip addresses in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, ip, ip-address

I am looking at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column, but I am not sure what type I should represent my ip addresses and ports. Based on
https://github.com/L0SG/DDPG_NIDS/blob/master/main.py, I could remove the dots and insert the resulting address, but I am not sure if that is best way. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

edit: Also how should I enter UTC-format time and dates into TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how you intend to use the address.  Are you considering any relationship between the fields?  For instance, is 1.2.3.4 supposed to be "close" to 1.2.3.5, or are they entirely distinct addresses?

If every address is distinct, you may as well let them be strings.  If you need the closeness, I suggest that you convert them either to four separate integer features, or a single 32-bit integer -- again, depending on the semantics in your modeling.

---

UPDATE FOR ADDED QUESTION

Same idea: how do you plan to use the dates?  I think the most flexible would be to convert the date to epoch (seconds after a standard time point), and use that 64-bit integer as the feature value.

Comment: Ah so are you saying I can just hash it since closeness does not matter to me?

Comment: Sure.  In fact, if closeness doesn't matter, why take the time and bother to hash at all?

Comment: Well the ip space is sort of big. So I thought of treating it as continuous columns via tf.feature_column.numeric_column. Which specific function should I be using if I am not using categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(...)?

Comment: I was thinking of straight `numeric_column`.  However, I think your most recent comment is an excellent point: with sparse IP addresses, hashing is likely to give you the same performance and save a little space, with only a tiny amount of time up front.  This will be less coding and easier to maintain than converting each IP address to its corresponding 32-bit integer.